# Specific TextView in GridView not updating on app init

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, textview, timertask

I have 4 `TextViews` in a `GridView` with a custom adapter in a given `Fragment`. My main `Activity` gets notified via a `TimerTask` to update the text color for the correct `TextView`. This works fine for all the `TextViews` except the first one when the app first starts. After that it works correctly like the rest of the `TextViews`.

In the `Fragment` in question:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.short_press_info_fragment, container, false);
    GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    infoAdapter = new ShortPressInfoAdapter(mKeyInfo, getActivity());
    grid.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
    return view; 
}
```

In the adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "inflating");
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        TextView text = texts[position] = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridItemText);
        Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "creating view");
        text.setText(mKeyInfo[position]);
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            break;
        case 1:
            text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            break;
        case 3:
            text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

In the main `Activity`:

```
public void emphasizeShort(final PressID p, final boolean b) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if(b) {
      Log.d(TAG, "setting short " + p + " to black");
      getShortTextView(p).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
    else {
      Log.d(TAG, "setting short " + p + " to white");
      getShortTextView(p).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
  }
});
}
```

The log shows me the same output no matter which `TextView` I'm trying to change when the app starts but the first `TextView` is the only one that simply doesn't change.

What would cause a `View` to ignore a change when an app starts but not after? And from this code I don't see why the first `TextView` is singled out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's the function that sends the request to emphasize the `TextView`s.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { // button pressed
    pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.d("TIMER_TASK", "short press "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime));
        mFourButtonListener.onShortPress(buttonID);
      }
    }, SHORT_PRESS_DELAY);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.d("TIMER_TASK", "long press "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime));
        mFourButtonListener.onLongPress(buttonID);
      }
    }, LONG_PRESS_DELAY);
    return true;
  } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime;
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    if (duration >= SHORT_PRESS_DELAY && duration < LONG_PRESS_DELAY)
      mFourButtonListener.onShortRelease(buttonID);
    else if (duration >= LONG_PRESS_DELAY)
      mFourButtonListener.onLongRelease(buttonID);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
}
```

I'm getting desperate.

Comment: which textview are you returning in  getShortTextView(p) ?

Comment: From the adapter: `texts[p]`

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about what you mean by "when the app first starts." It seems like you're updating the color of your textview in `emphasizeShort` in response to a touch, and this is working? Are you also calling this method when the Activity or Fragment is created, which is where it is not working?

Comment: What I mean by "when the app first starts" is: the app starts the main activity; when the user performs a short press on any of the buttons EXCEPT the first, the correct change of text color occurs. From then on all button presses perform as expected. I believe @j__m has a possible answer as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of missing code here, but if you're having a problem with it not working when the app is first starting, then the problem is likely caused by `runOnUiThread`, which is simply not reliable at startup. (i.e., not every task posted is guaranteed to run.)

Add a class-level `Handler` variable

```
Handler h;
```

and create it during `onCreate`

```
h = new Handler();
```

Then use `h.post()` instead of `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it was the only reason there was an issue as I also used the advice given by @M-WaJeEh to clean up the fragment altogether but now it works so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If no. of `TextView`s will stay 4, no matter what then **don't** use `GridView`. Use `LineareLayout` instead. Anyways your current approach will stop working if you add more `TextView`s. At first glance your `getView()` is faulty, you must do it like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "inflating");
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    } // <<<<------------------- 
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridItemText);
    Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "creating view");
    text.setText(mKeyInfo[position]);
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        break;
    case 1:
        text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
        break;
    case 2:
        text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        break;
    case 3:
        text.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    } 
    return v;
}
```

Basically you must perform all state related operations every time `getView()` is called due to `View` recycling.

BTW why you are keeping reference to yourself in `texts` array? Its very very **bad practice**. Why do you need this?

If you want to change the colors at later stage then you need to change your whole logic.  You need to do something similar to this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int[] colors = new int[4];

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    colors[0] =  context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    colors[1] =  context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow);
    colors[2] =  context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
    colors[3] =  context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
}

@Override
public int getCount() { 
    return colors.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) { 
    return colors[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "inflating");
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    } // <<<<------------------- 
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridItemText);
    Log.d("GRID_VIEW", "creating view");
    text.setText(mKeyInfo[position]);
    text.setBackgroundColor(colors[position]); 
    return v;
}
// call this method to change colors at later stage
public void changeColor(int position, int color){
    colors[position] = color;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// call this method to change text at later stage
public void changeText(int position, String text){
    mKeyInfo[position] = text;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: I initially assumed (being a relative android newbie) that `GridView` was the way to go, but clearly there was an easier way to do it.
In any case, thanks for the good advice.